# Pattern matching on numpy char array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get the resulting boolean array `mask` by testing each position in the single char array `arr` on the condition:

```
(arr == 'A') | (arr == 'C') | (arr == 'G') | (arr == 'T')
```

For Example:

```
>>> arr = np.array(list('AT.NGA-TCGACA'))
>>> arr
array(['A', 'T', '.', 'N', 'G', 'A', '-', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'A'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> mask = (arr == 'A') | (arr == 'C') | (arr == 'G') | (arr == 'T')
>>> mask
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Is there a shortcut for this kind of test in the spirit of

```
string in 'ACGT'
```

for arrays that would be just as fast as the explicit test above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `np.in1d`:

```
>>> arr = np.random.choice(['A','B','C','D','G','T'], 100, replace=True)
>>> arr
array(['C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'T', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C',
       'G', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A',
       'B', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'T', 'D', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'B',
       'D', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'D', 'D',
       'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'B', 'G', 'G', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'B',
       'C', 'B', 'A', 'T', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'G',
       'G', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'G',
       'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'B'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Then,

```
>>> np.in1d(arr, ['A','C','G','T'])
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
        True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Comment: If the 2nd list is small enough (compared to the first) `in1d` does the kind of test used by OP - just written with a loop.  Check its code.

Comment: How small is small enough?

Comment: `if len(ar2) < 10 * len(ar1) ** 0.145`.  It does `for a in ar2: mask |= (ar1 == a)`.

Comment: Does it make a difference for this function whether `['A','C','G','T']` or `{'A','C','G','T'}` is passed?

Comment: @Cleb ... Why don't you try it out? But yes, because the second argument must be an array-like, and `set` is not.

Comment: I thought you knew :) But yes, I will check. Was just wondering as look-ups are normally faster for sets than for lists.

Comment: @Cleb it is almost certainly *not* using a list or set-lookup, but some underlying `numpy` stuff.

Comment: OK, then it won't make any difference then. Thanks for clarifying, I am never sure about these things...

Comment: @Cleb Also, for such a small list, the differenes between set-and-list lookup will be negligible. Indeed, it may be faster to look up the list

Comment: This is indeed at least as fast as the explicitly written condition in my question  based on a few tests I tried (maybe 5% faster even). Marked solved!

Answer (score 0):

in `numpy` you can use `setdiff1d(a, b)`

example:

```
a = np.array(['A','C','G','T','A','C','G','T','M'])
b = np.array(['A','C','G','T'])
diff = np.setdiff1d(a, b)
print diff
```

Comment: which ends up delegating the task to `in1d`.

Comment: @Cleb the `diff` is the difference array it can be empty if no other than mentioned 4 symbols is in the tested input or non empty otherwise. I don't know how isosceleswheel plans to utilize it.

Comment: For some reason this takes exactly 2x longer than the answer I accepted...